# Deny all requests to a specific sub folder for virtual host

Tags: apache

All requests to `http://example.com` are redirected to https and then proxy passed to my application server. So far so good.

Now I want to deny all requests to a specific sub folder, that is `http://example.com/dev`. How do I accomplish that?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </Location>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/server.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl/intermediate.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to NOT have that directory there. But to answer your question, I would probably use a <Directory> directive with "Require all denied".

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). But where should I put this <Directory>? Inside <VirtualHost>?

Comment: Within the https virtualhost. You might want to look at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory for some example and the exact syntax.